# Increasing Font Size in a JButton

Tags: java, button, fonts, size

I am at a loss of what to do for the finalization of my term project. I am working on a Connect Four game and I'd like to increase the font size inside of a JButton. I'm relatively new to programming and I haven't worked anything with fonts yet. I'd just like to at least double the font inside of the button to make it more visible during gameplay. Can someone help me, or point me into the direction of finding a solution? Thanks! My code is below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Connect implements ActionListener {





private JFrame window = new JFrame("Connect Four by Steven and Anthony");    
private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel myPanelB = new JPanel();
private JButton[][] myButtons = new JButton[6][7];
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[7];
private boolean win = false;

private int count = 5;
private int count2 = 5;
private int count3 = 5;
private int count4 = 5;
private int count5 = 5;
private int count6 = 5;
private int count7 = 5;
private int countA = 0;
private String letter = "";

public boolean checkHorizontalWin(String letter) {
for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length; y++) {        
    for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length - 3; x++) {
        if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 1].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 2].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 3].getText().equals(letter)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}


public boolean checkVerticalWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkDiagonalToTheLeftWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length - 3; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x + 1].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x + 2].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x + 3].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkDiagonalToTheRightWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 3; x < myButtons[y].length; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x - 1].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x - 2].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x - 3].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}



public Connect(){
    window.setSize(800,700);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,7));
    myPanelB.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        myPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j ++){
            myButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
            myPanelB.add(myButtons[i][j]);
        }
    }
    window.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    window.add(myPanelB, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    countA++;
    if (countA % 2 == 0)
        letter = "X";
    else
        letter = "O";



    if (e.getSource() == buttons[0]){
        myButtons[count][0].setText(letter);
        count --;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[1]){
        myButtons[count2][1].setText(letter);
        count2 --;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[2]){
        myButtons[count3][2].setText(letter);
        count3--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[3]){
        myButtons[count4][3].setText(letter);
        count4--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[4]){
        myButtons[count5][4].setText(letter);
        count5--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[5]){
        myButtons[count6][5].setText(letter);
        count6--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[6]){
        myButtons[count7][6].setText(letter);
        count7--;
    }
    if (myButtons[0][0].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][0].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][1].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][1].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][2].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][2].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][3].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][3].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][4].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][4].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][5].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][5].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    }                       

   if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
}

if (checkHorizontalWin(letter)
    || checkVerticalWin(letter)
    || checkDiagonalToTheLeftWin(letter)
    || checkDiagonalToTheRightWin(letter)
    ) {
        win = true;

        if (win == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " has won!");
            System.exit(0);
        }    
    }
}




/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Connect();
}
}
```

Answer (score 42):

You can use:

```
button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
```

- `"Arial"` is obviously the name of the font being used.
- `Font.PLAIN` means plain text (as opposed to bold or italic).
- `40` is the font size (using the same numbering system for font size as Microsoft Word)

[Javadoc for JComponent.setFont()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29)

[Javadoc for Java.awt.Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)

Comment: Should I call this in actionPerformed?

Comment: It's working fine with `setFont(Font)`. But there is only one problem, it also affect the size of your button if font size is large enough ...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this will work, but looking at the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) docs, there is a [setFont(Font font)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29) method you can call. You can try passing it a [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) created with the font size you'd like using the `Font(String name, int style, int size)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

To change the font in java swing:

```
name_Button.setFont(new FontUIResource(String name, int style, int size));
```

- `name` the font name
- `style` the style constant for the font
- `size` the point size of the font