# How to check the JButton[3][3] text value in the method from other class?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a problem with my TicTacToe game. 
I want to write a method to check the winner condition. 
In my Arbiter class,hasWinner() method  i want to check the text value from JButton from the TicTacToeGUI. For example if the JButton[0][0], JButton[0][1],JButton[0][2] are equals. We will have a message that someone won the game. 
But i don't have idea how to pass the JButton array to this hasWinner().

I try to keep my game logic in the Arbiter class.

I have three classes. Main class, TicTacToeGUI and Arbiter.

TicTacToeGUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class TicTacToeGUI implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton[][] board;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    private JMenuItem quit;
    private Arbiter arbiter;


    public TicTacToeGUI() {
        super();
        this.arbiter = new Arbiter();
        initializeMenuBar();
        initializeBoard();
    }

    public void initializeBoard() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe v0.1");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //Creating MENU
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));

        //Add a JButton[3][3] array and actionListener
        board = new JButton[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = new JButton("");
                panel.add(board[i][j]);
                board[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public void initializeMenuBar() {
        //Create menu Bar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("MENU");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        menu.add(newGame);

        quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menu.add(quit);
        //Add functionality to newGame menu item.
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                arbiter.setGame();
            }
        });
        //Add functionality to quit menu item.
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
        arbiter.setText(pressed);

    }
    public void winner(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Mamy zwycięzcę!!!",
                "A winner is:",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Arbiter:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Arbiter {
    private int player = 1;
    private boolean winner = false;

    public void setGame(){

    }
    public void reset(){
        setGame();
    }
    public void hasWinner(JButton btn){
        TicTacToeGUI win = new TicTacToeGUI();
        if((btn[0][0] == btn[0][1]) && (btn[0][0] == btn[0][2])){
            win.winner();
        }
    }

    public void setText(JButton btn){
        if (btn.getText().length() == 0){
            btn.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 60));
            btn.setText(player == 1 ? "O" : "X");
            switchPlayer(player);
        }
        hasWinner();
    }

    private void switchPlayer(int currentPlayer){
        this.player = player == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a few issues, but first, do you have something like eclipse or netbeans IDE ? I find that using the debugger to set break points and inspecting the objects to be a great learning tool.

Comment: im using an IntelliJ

Comment: I would create one instance of Arbiter and within the actionPerformed make your call to arbiter.hasWinner() but as I mentioned there are a couple of other issues. I don't have time right now to go over all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your statement `I try to keep my game logic in the Arbiter class` is a good way to look at it. However, in my opinion, that would mean `Arbiter` should never be able to directly affect the GUI.

So in this edited `Arbiter` class you will notice a few differences.

```
public class Arbiter {
    private int player = 1;
    private String[][] gameValues = new String[3][3];

    public void setGame() {
        gameValues = new String[3][3];
    }

    public void reset() {
        setGame();
    }

    public boolean hasWinner() {
        if((gameValues[0][0].equals(gameValues[0][1])) && (gameValues[0][0].equals(gameValues[0][2]))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setText(int x, int y) {
        if(player == 0) {
            gameValues[x][y] = "X";
            switchPlayer(1);
        } else {
            gameValues[x][y] = "O";
            switchPlayer(0);
        }
    }

    public String getBoardValue(int x, int y) {
        return gameValues[x][y];
    }

    public String[][] getBoardValues() {
        return gameValues;
    }

    private void switchPlayer(int newPlayer) {
        this.player = newPlayer;
    }
}
```

The main ones being `hasWinner` now returns a boolean so it is easy for the GUI to tell if there is a winner or not and a new variable called `gameValues`. `gameValues` stores all the current values of the game and can be accessed by methods such as `getBoardValue` and `getBoardValues`. This helps the project follow the `Single Responsibility Principle` which basically means one class should only handle one responsibility.

Next, the GUI class. You will notice a few differences here as well.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TicTacToeGUI implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton[][] board;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    private JMenuItem quit;
    private Arbiter arbiter;


    public TicTacToeGUI() {
        super();
        this.arbiter = new Arbiter();
        initializeMenuBar();
        initializeBoard();
    }

    public void initializeBoard() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe v0.1");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //Creating MENU
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));

        //Add a JButton[3][3] array and actionListener
        board = new JButton[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = new JButton("");
                panel.add(board[i][j]);
                board[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        refreshBoardValues();
    }

    public void initializeMenuBar() {
        //Create menu Bar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("MENU");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        menu.add(newGame);

        quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menu.add(quit);
        //Add functionality to newGame menu item.
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                arbiter.setGame();
            }
        });
        //Add functionality to quit menu item.
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(board[i][j] == (JButton) e.getSource()) {
                    arbiter.setText(i, j);
                    refereshBoardValue(i, j);
                    if(arbiter.hasWinner()) {
                        winner();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void refreshBoardValues() {
        String[][] currentValues = arbiter.getBoardValues();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j].setText(currentValues[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void refereshBoardValue(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y].setText(arbiter.getBoardValue(x, y));
    }

    private void winner(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Mamy zwycięzcę!!!",
                "A winner is:",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

The main differences are the methods `refreshBoardValues` and `refereshBoardValue` whose job is to get an up to date value from the game when an action is performed. The main `actionPerformed` performed logic has changed as well.

It now gets the position of a `JButton` and tells the arbiter that button in position xy has been pressed. This updates the game value in position xy and then that value is sent back to the GUI and reflected on the `JButton`. Finally the a check is carried out to see if any win conditions are made. The rest is the same.

Comment: Your answer was really helpfull. I wanted to go some kind of this way, but I dont have enough knowlegde.

I changed a little bit the TicTacToeGUI class. I add a disableButton method to prevent changing from X to O for example. And a reset method to reset all the buttons. 

I have a problem with your example couse the winner condition is working only for the first row. I cant figure it out how to fix this.

And you know maybe how i can change font size using setFont ?

Comment: @Headsman Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20462394/4601149) for font stuff. As for the win conditions have a shot at it first. It might be worth looking up TicTacToe win conditions online and seeing if you can implement that first

Comment: okey i finished this. Its working. Thanks for your advice. It helpes me a lot.